# The recording being played in Pawn Sacrifice while Jefferson Airplane's "White Rabbit" plays

Tags: pawn-sacrifice

Does anyone know more about the recording being played in *Pawn Sacrifice* where "Jefferson Airplane - White Rabbit" is playing where the priest wakes up and asks what he is listening to? Here is what I could make out:

> look at the godless soviet union and their relentless march across europe pawn sacrifice

Comment: Something related to [Worldwide Church of God?](http://www.historyvshollywood.com/reelfaces/pawn-sacrifice/)

Answer (score 1):

While I can't guarantee the provenance of this, there is a [site that has a transcript](https://www.springfieldspringfield.co.uk/movie_script.php?movie=pawn-sacrifice) that has the above line in it, in the following form:

> When he sees that he's finished? When he sees it coming. And breaks all up inside.
>
> Their goal is nothing short of world domination. And unless they are stopped, that goal will soon be within their grasp. Look at the godless Soviet Union and their relentless march across Eastern Europe. Look at the illegitimate state of Israel, whose expansionist ambitions have usurped Palestine from its true heirs in the kingdom of Judah. Indeed, the people of Israel are not even the real Jews. That tribe was taken captive by King Nebuchadrezzar of Babylon in 600 B.C...
>
> Bobby, turn the music down.
>
> He doesn't want the Russians to know what plane we're taking.

Shortly after this, the transcripts indicate he takes out the music and puts in a homemade tape of the Worldwide Church of God (referenced a few times in the scripts), which may be where the transcript gets the lines, as several different (Pink, green and yellow) versions of the script that show the first line (An interview with Fischer) do not show any of the rest of the lines.